# Copy texture to screen buffer without drawing quad (opengl)

Tags: opengl

Is there a fast function to blit a texture to the screen buffer (without using extensions)?
I need an Inverse of `glCopyTexImage2D()`.

Does such a function exist?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The closest you will get is [glBlitFramebuffer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBlitFramebuffer). Which, as the name suggests, is for framebuffers. Yes, [framebuffers can include textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object), but I wouldn't attempt to use this as a replacement for drawing textures with quads. You'll get far better performance for drawing lots of textures by using quads than blitting framebuffers.

Also, drawing a quad *is* a fast function for drawing a texture.

Comment: Drawing a quad, even considering the state changes to make it fullscreen/no-depth-test/etc, is extremely fast. The slowest part of it is the buffer-to-texture copy, but the draw can be fast enough that a ping-pong approach with buffers can be faster. Blitting to or from the backbuffer, or worse the frontbuffer, is always *extremely* slow.

Comment: on some opengl implementations glBlitFramebuffer actually uses quad rendering. And instead of something like 'memcpy' gpu uses full pipeline to blit one fbo to the other. But on the other hand it gives the ability to perform scaling and filtering.

Comment: On my system (GTX 660), doing a glBlitFramebuffer from a texture (wrapped in a framebuffer) to the main framebuffer is about 20 microseconds slower than drawing a quad. Fascinating.

Comment: On my GTX460 I couldn't measure any performance difference between blitting and drawing a fullscreen quad.

Comment: The above applies to copying from FBO to FBO. But when I copy from FBO to backbuffer, a fullscreen quad is a tiny bit faster. Copying from a higher resolution buffer to a lower resolution one is much slower when using blitting though.

Comment: Aside from using quads, triangles can also be used to blit to screen with added advantage that it is more cache friendly (packed tighter in memory): https://rauwendaal.net/2014/06/14/rendering-a-screen-covering-triangle-in-opengl/